# I don't see Office 2007 document type in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I just installed MOSS 2007 SP2 and configured my site.

When I go to create a new document library, I don't see document types of Office 2007 documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defaults to the Office 2003 formats because most customers get SharePoint 2007 before getting Office 2007. If you want to set up a custom template using one of the Office 2007 formats, you can.

Comment: Thanks Tom :) Could you please suggest me some links regarding this if you know any?